# How to know the end of SWF embedded in another SWF

Tags: javascript, html, flash

we created a video platform where we can upload elearning in the form of SWF. The platform is a webpage created in .Net and using javascript. 
   To know the end of a SWF, we look at the Totalframe property and when the currentframe equals it, whe show a "Finish" button to load a new page.Here is the code:

```
        var initialInterval = setInterval(function() {
        var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myFlashContent");
        clearInterval(initialInterval);

        totalFrame = obj.TGetProperty("/", 5) * 0.99;
        var flashInterval = setInterval(function() {
            var currentFrame = obj.TGetProperty("/", 4);
            if (currentFrame >= totalFrame) {
                // Sauvegarde
                $('.btn-primary').removeAttr("disabled");
                clearInterval(flashInterval);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
```

Our problem occurs when the SWF(the elearning content) is embedded in another SWF (GUI). The GUI.swf is the one loaded, so if I look at the total frame of the current frame, it's always 1. Even when I click on the "next" button in the GUI, that loads a new page in the Content.SWF.

I cannot merge the GUI.swf with Content.swf, so, is there a way to know with javascript the current page in the Content.swf?

Thanks,
Matthieu T.

Comment: The easiest way would be to call something in JS **from** content.swf when it finishes playing. That would require one line of code in content.swf's last frame (`ExternalInterface.call('someJavascriptMethod')`) and will eliminate the need of checking current frame periodically in JS. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by *embedded* SWF? Do you mean it is loaded by GUI? I'm not sure how `TGetProperty()` exactly works, but if it supports path to a timeline as a first argument, you could address loaded SWF that way... you will just need to know the path. If content.swf gets on screen, its timeline can be accessed with a path which depends on the display list structure of GUI.swf.

Comment: Sorry for the delay!

You got good idea, but first, I can't access JS in content.swf. I'm not the one who did it, it was created with a elearning application (adobe captivate).

Then, when I mean embedded SWF, it's because the content.swf is loaded by GUI. We tried to change TGetProperty path argument, but it didn't work (only returns 1). 

Any other ideas?
Thanks,